Asynchronous message authentication and authorization in Apps script using Google Chat API

Google Chat APP Asynchronous Message Sending Issue

According to the Google developer manual, authentication is not required when interacting with app users, but it is necessary for asynchronous messages. (Reference: https://developers.google.com/workspace/chat/authenticate-authorize?hl=en)


I tried using Chat.Spaces.Messages.create in Appscript, but a message about app settings appeared, and when attempting to allow it, a 400 invalid scope error occurred.

Therefore, it seemed that additional permissions were needed, so I accessed the Google Workspace Admin account and granted permissions to the service account, but it was of no use.


As explained above.

Add oauthScopes to appsscript.json in Apps Script
Add chat scope to Google Chat API Service account in Google Workspace Admin > Security > API Management > Domain-wide Delegation menu

I hope you can successfully send asynchronous messages in Google Chat App.
